# How do I rigorously prove Is (R X Z) U ( Z X R) = R X Z false?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I know that $\Bbb{Z}$ is the subset of $\Bbb{R}$, so all the elements in $\Bbb{Z}$ consist in the set $\Bbb{R}$, but elements of $\Bbb{R}$ do not consist in $\Bbb{Z}$. If we do the union of the Cartesian product of $\Bbb{(R \times Z)}$ and $\Bbb{(Z\times R)}$, we will end up getting some elements like $(0.21,0.1)$ which are not the elements of $\Bbb{Z}$, thus the union cannot be equal to $\Bbb{R \times Z}$.

How do I rigorously prove my argument?

Thanks

Comment: No, you don't get $(0.21,0.1)$, but you do get $(1,0.1)$, and that's good enough.

Comment: Do you understand the comment, and the answer that has been posted?

Comment: It's not polite to ask for help, and then refuse to engage when help is offered.

Comment: @GerryMyerson hey man thanks for the help. I was in the middle of the college move in so couldn’t check stack. Again thanks for responding it was helpful.

Comment: @GerryMyerson so is giving example good enough ?

Comment: Yes, giving a counterexample is enough to prove the equation is false (provided you explain why it's a counterexample).

Comment: @GerryMyerson I see . Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to prove. You have to discard it. One counter example is good enough.

If $x\in \Bbb{R}\times\Bbb{Z}$,
then $x\in (\Bbb{R}\times\Bbb{Z})\cup(\Bbb{Z}\times\Bbb{R}).$
Therefore $\Bbb{R}\times\Bbb{Z}\subset (\Bbb{R}\times\Bbb{Z})\cup(\Bbb{Z}\times\Bbb{R}).$

Clearly, $y=(m,0.a_1a_2...)\in (\Bbb{R}\times\Bbb{Z})\cup (\Bbb{Z}\times\Bbb{R})$

, but $y\notin \Bbb{R}\times\Bbb{Z}$

Comment: Thanks. Gotcha.

Comment: You're welcome!